# vlc on mac, how to just play videos/songs without the main menu with media library/playlist coming up

Tags: vlc

I just want to click videos and have them play, not have to close this annoying main menu screen everytime, I googled, checked settings, is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of guesswork required based on very little information, but try
Prefs > Video > Show video within the main window.

That will make it so the playlist window is re-used as the video display window.

Comment: it was already ticked, the main menu thing still pops up when I load a video, I noticed if I keep vlc open it doesn't, so maybe I just will leave it on when I'm using it.

Comment: Half the 'problem' with VLC [the other half being that it's a multi-platform cross-port] is that many of the prefs interact with each other. There's a whole lot of 'suck it & see' you need to do before you find your ideal modus operandi. One thing to note; you have to quit & re-launch the app for most prefs tweaks to activate.

Comment: This is why I will never upgrade past vlc 1.1.12.  This insistance on being a bedia library makes any later version unusable.

Comment: @MarcWilson - tbh, I like how I can stack an entire binge-watch series in there & have it remember where I got to. My only wish is it would remember that through restarts, without me having to specifically save & reload it, like most other Mac apps do these days.